# ProvidePlugin not working for jquery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I want to include jquery globally to my react application. I am using a lot of third party plugins which uses jquery. So I tried doing it via webpack's ProvidePlugin

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            React: 'react',
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            _: 'lodash'
        }),
```

Now I have removed all the import statements from the components. But $ is not mapped to jquery module. When I do ctrl+click on $, it takes me to dom.js. For React:'react', it is working.

How can I solve it?

These are the errors when I try to run my project

```
ion.rangeSlider.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at ion.rangeSlider.js:21
    at ion.rangeSlider.js:23
(anonymous) @ ion.rangeSlider.js:21
(anonymous) @ ion.rangeSlider.js:23
markers.js:450 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at markers.js:450
```

Comment: have you installed `jquery` by `npm i jquery --save` ?

Comment: Yes. It's present in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a safe way to provide jQuery, etc. to the context of each module during the bundling **BUT** you must import your jquery inside your code somewhere

```
import 'jquery'
```

or

```
require('jquery')
```

If you don't do that, your modules won't be able to consume jQuery

Comment: Import was creating multiple version clashes. Therefore I wanted something global. I used import $ from 'jquery', but it was giving me $(...).ionRangeSlider is not a function. And this was "not" an error due to wrong placement of jquery script before ionRangeSlider script, It is due to jquery.

Comment: You have also to consider that maybe some plugins don't support CommonJS